# не могу понять что делаю не так helm 3

Tags: kubernetes, helm

Всем привет. Изучаю хелм и куб.
пытаюсь разобраться в го шаблонизаторе. Немного не понимаю как он работает
вот мой простенький деплоймент

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: {{ .Values.port }}
              protocol: TCP
        - env:
          - name: PORT
            value: {{ .Values.port | quote }}
          - name: LOGS
            value: {{ .Value.logs | quote }}
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
```

файл с переменными

values.yaml

```
port: 8080
logs: "/logs/access.log"

replicaCount: 1

image:
  repository: #
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: "develop"
```

в случае с containerPort: {{ .Values.port }} всё работает прекрасно
но когда я начинаю подставлять перменные в контейнер это не работает

проверяю helm lint или helm install получаю такую ошибку:

```
gitlab-runner:~$ helm install test ./test --dry-run --debug
install.go:173: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:190: [debug] CHART PATH: /home/gitlab-runner/test

Error: template: test/templates/deployment.yaml:28:28: executing "test/templates/deployment.yaml" at <.Value.logs>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.logs
helm.go:88: [debug] template: test/templates/deployment.yaml:28:28: executing "test/templates/deployment.yaml" at <.Value.logs>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.logs
```

подскажите что не так делаю.
И еще такой вопрос, как вы задаете переменные в контейнеры ? собираю в гитлабе дальше хочу выкатывать хельмом в куб.

Answer (score 0):

В helm нет предопределенного объекта `.Value`, есть `.Values`. Что бы избежать подобных ошибок в будущем, лучше всего использовать IDE с поддержкой обработки helm-чартов и с автодополнением по ним.

Еще посмотрите [документацию](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/) на предмет предопределенных объектов helm.